# Finite differences to ODE in polar coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, polar-coordinates, finite-differences

I have an equation of finite differences as follows:

$$\frac{X_1(r+\epsilon)-X_1(r)}{ \frac{\epsilon~\beta}{2~r+\epsilon} }
+ \frac{X_1(r-\epsilon)-X_1(r)}{ \frac{\epsilon~\beta}{2~r-\epsilon} }
= \frac{2X_1(r)-X(r)}{ \frac{1}{r~\epsilon} }$$

For $\epsilon\rightarrow0$ this equation is supposed to lead to the ODE:

$$ \frac{d^2X_1(r)}{dr^2} +\frac{1}{r}\frac{dX_1(r)}{dr} - \beta X_1(r) =  -\frac{\beta}{2} X(r) $$

But I absolutely don't see how. Can you tell me which rule to follow to obtain this step?
I have solved a similar rectangular problem in cartesian coordinates before without any problems, but I haven't found anything to achieve this step for a cylindrical problem in polar coordinates. Any advice?

The author were I got these equations from didn't made any further explanation on this step, so I assume it must be something simple, I just cannot see.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taylor expansion:

\begin{align}
\text{LHS} &= \frac{X_1(r+\epsilon)-X_1(r)}{ \frac{\epsilon~\beta}{2~r+\epsilon} }
+ \frac{X_1(r-\epsilon)-X_1(r)}{ \frac{\epsilon~\beta}{2~r-\epsilon} } \\
&= \frac{X_1(r) +\epsilon X_1'(r) +\frac 12 \epsilon^2 X_1''(r) +O(\epsilon^3) -X_1(r)}{ \frac{\epsilon~\beta}{2~r+\epsilon} }
+ \frac{X_1(r) -\epsilon X_1'(r) +\frac 12\epsilon^2 X_1''(r) +O(\epsilon^3)-X_1(r)}{ \frac{\epsilon~\beta}{2~r-\epsilon} } \\
&= \frac{\epsilon X_1'(r) +\frac 12\epsilon^2 X_1''(r) +O(\epsilon^3)}{ \frac{\epsilon~\beta}{2~r+\epsilon} }
+ \frac{-\epsilon X_1'(r) +\frac 12\epsilon^2 X_1''(r) +O(\epsilon^3)}{ \frac{\epsilon~\beta}{2~r-\epsilon} } \\
&= \frac 1 \beta \left( \frac{ X_1'(r) +\frac 12\epsilon X_1''(r) +O(\epsilon^2)}{ \frac{1}{2~r+\epsilon} }
+ \frac{- X_1'(r) +\frac 12\epsilon X_1''(r) +O(\epsilon^2)}{ \frac{1}{2~r-\epsilon} } \right)\\
&= \frac 1 \beta \left( (2r+\epsilon)( X_1'(r) +\frac 12\epsilon X_1''(r) +O(\epsilon^2) )
+ (2r-\epsilon)(- X_1'(r) +\frac 12\epsilon X_1''(r) +O(\epsilon^2)) \right)\\
&= \frac 1 \beta \left( 2r \epsilon X_1''(r)  + 2\epsilon X_1'(r) +O(\epsilon^2) \right)\\
&= \frac {2\epsilon} \beta \left( r  X_1''(r) + X_1'(r) +O(\epsilon) \right)\\
\end{align}

Plugging back in,

\begin{align}
\frac {2\epsilon} \beta \left( r  X_1''(r) + X_1'(r) +O(\epsilon) \right) = r\epsilon (2X_1(r)-X(r))
\end{align}

Dividing through by $\frac {2r\epsilon}\beta$ and taking $\epsilon\to0$,

\begin{align}
X_1''(r) + \frac 1r X_1'(r) - \beta X_1(r) = -\frac \beta 2 X(r)
\end{align}

This method works.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, it has to be $\frac{\beta}{2}$ on the right side, so your solution is correct. It looks nice, thank you very much! But do you have any source for this approach? Is this the usual way to go? Or did you just guess and try out?

Comment: The signs still don't match... In any case, it's a "usual way to go" when deriving equations.

Comment: that's true, I've overseen this mistake. But they should match, I checked the initial equations again.

Comment: there was a sign mistake on my side, I corrected both, question and answer. Should be correct now. (Though I don't know if the reviewer will accept my edit) Could you please tell me what made you choose this approach? Is it obvious? Then I will also accept your answer.

Comment: The sign of the RHS is still different, but it doesn't look like my mistake. In any casae it's a standard approach. Google for the derivation of various PDEs, like the heat and wave equation and they all do the same thing.